# Fill grouped lines with background

Tags: draw.io

I want to create a grouped object with multiple lines and fill the object with a background color.
As you can see, however, the background does not respect the lines as a frame.

[image]

Is it possible to fill only the grouped object within the lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible using grouped lines (style will be applied to whole group which have shape of rectangle) , but you can create custom shape using *Arrange > Insert > Shape*. You can find description how to do that [here](https://desk.draw.io/support/solutions/articles/16000052874-how-to-create-and-edit-shapes-) or [here](https://desk.draw.io/support/solutions/articles/16000070744-how-to-create-custom-stencils-in-draw-io-using-the-text-editor-step-by-step-). If you want to edit shape after inserting it, you can do that using *Edit Shape* from *Style* tab in format panel on right (it is also possible to edit some of draw.io shapes).

Example shape similar to your image:

```
<shape h="100" w="100" aspect="variable" strokewidth="inherit">  
  <foreground>    
    <path>      
      <move x="50" y="0" />
      <line x="80" y="40" />      
      <line x="100" y="50" />      
      <line x="60" y="100" />      
      <line x="30" y="100" />     
      <line x="0" y="60" />      
      <close />     
    </path>    
    <fillstroke />    
  </foreground>  
</shape>
```

Remeber to use `<fillstroke />` or `<fill />` if you want colored background.